# Perron eigenvector of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

We have a "wide" matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}_+^{k \times n}$ where $n$ is usually large (e.g. 10000) and $k$ is small (e.g. 5 to 10). All of its entries are positive.

Now, we introduce $B=AA^T\in\mathbb{R}_+^{k \times k}$ - a small, symmetric and positive matrix.

From Perron-Frobenius, we have a positive eigenvector $\mathbf{v}_P\in\mathbb{R}_+^k$ and $\lambda_P>0$ such that $B\mathbf{v}_P=\lambda_P\mathbf{v}_P$. In current solution we calculate the Perron eigenvalue and eigenvector numerically (with Python+scipy).

Now - knowing that $B$ is constructed as $AA^T$,  I was wondering if there exists some kind of *formula* to calculate $\mathbf{v}_P$ and $\lambda_P$ *directly* - preferably straight from the $A$ matrix, using a bunch of *simple* operations like matrix multiplication etc., without resorting to methods like numerical/iterational calculation of eigenvectors.

Any further insights into how $\mathbf{v}_P$ and $\lambda_P$ relate to the initial matrix $A$  are also highly appreciated :)

Comment: Schur-Jordan Factorization: $$AA^{T}=QDQ^{T}$$ where $Q$ is an orthogonal matrix containing your eigenvectors $v_{p}$ and $D$ is your diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of $AA^{T}$.

Comment: @deerclaysup It is notable that your approach is equivalent to using the SVD of $A$. Both processes are usually done iteratively, which means it doesn't quite match what the asker wants

Comment: @BenGrossmann - so am I right to assume that it's unlikely there exists a non-iterative solution?

Comment: @WojciechKozaczewski I don't know, but that's what I suspect as well